# grafana working with time difference influxdb

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I have a measurements like this:

> value  |  time
> 35101 | 1599719557000000000
> 35101 | 1599733107000000000
> 35102 | 1599733127000000000

I would like to show, maybe in a graph bar, the time difference between the last value and the previous value of a single value. I mean:

`difference(1599719557000000000- 1599733107000000000)` for value `35101`

Is it possible?
I reached this point:

[image: Grafana dashboard]

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

InfluxDB [ELAPSED](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/functions/#elapsed) function helps to find the time difference between subsequent timestamps

In the measurement given in the question,

```
SELECT ELAPSED(value, 1s) FROM tagId WHERE value = 35101
```

should give the time between subsequent timestamps